# Install Two Instances of WPF Application on Same Machine

Tags: wpf, installation

I have a WPF application.  I used Visual Studio to publish it to a folder on my machine.  I then clicked on the application to run it.  Before running it, the application asked me if it is ok to install it.  I answered in the affirmative.  Then I changed the config file in Visual Studio to point to another database instance and published to a different folder.  I clicked on this new application to run it.  This time I was told that I cannot install the application as it was already installed on my machine.  Any way around this issue?

Comment: How do you install the app? If you're using ClickOnce you should change the name of second instance.

Comment: Here more info regarding the ClickOnce: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects